# unable to upload nfts using metaplex

Tags: command-line-interface, solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine

while am uploading Nft asset to Solana network and have this error :

```
 Beginning the upload for 22 (img+json) pairs
started at: 1646166389888
initializing candy machine
Error deploying config to Solana network. Error: Invalid config, there must be a symbol.
at createCandyMachineV2 
(C:\Users\Desktop\my_project\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\helpers\accounts.ts:126:11)
at uploadV2 
(C:\Users\Desktop\my_project\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\commands\upload.ts:133:45)
at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Desktop\my_project\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\candy- 
machine-v2-cli.ts:228:21)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
upload was not successful, please re-run. Error: Invalid config, there must be a symbol.
at createCandyMachineV2 
(C:\Users\Desktop\my_project\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\helpers\accounts.ts:126:11)
at 
uploadV2(C:\Users\Desktop\my_project\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\commands\upload.ts:133:45)
at Command.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\Desktop\my_project\metaplex\js\packages\cli\src\candymachinev2-cli.ts:228:21)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I was uploading the assets through CLI using this command:

```
ts-node metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload  -e devnet -k 
config/solana/devnet.json  -cp config.json  metaplex/assets
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the guides on the web would recommend having `symbol: ""` but the latest update in Metaplex Candy Machine (0.0.2) actually expects non-empty value here for your NFT's JSON files.

So the fix is simply updating the `symbol` field to have some value in it, e.g. `symbol: "TEST_NFT",`

The full explanation is [here](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/preparing-assets)

Answer (score 0):

Using metaplex-0.0.2 I could mint nft's with `symbol:""`

[image]

Looks like you dont have have correct config for the nft asset.

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "symbol": "",
  "image": "2.png",
  "properties": {
    "files": [
      {
        "url": "2.png",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "creators": [
      {
        "address": "21J9Vk6pX34pPW18gLxGj5Am6czmeKC6CEtQChztAuKY",
        "share": 100
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try with command like this

```
ts-node C:/Users/aditya/Desktop/PracticeCodes/NftMinting/~/deprecated-clis/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.
ts upload \ -e devnet \ -k payer.json \ -cp config.json \  ./assets
```

Comment: Please try to elaborate on what those commands are doing and how they function to solve the problem.